# Disable/modify Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

So I'm part of a project to develop an online testing tool for my university's language programme. We're trying to keep the system completely HTML/JS/CSS based so we don't have to deal with plugins and compatibility and such. Currently we have sound files for the listening portion of the examination which we would like to be played only a specified number of times. We have JS in place to stop the obvious sort of tomfoolery, such as changing the value of `timesPlayed` or directly fetching the mp3 file with cURL or a separate tab. However, Chrome's Developer Tools, while invaluable to us developers, also allows a very simple means of getting at the sound data: press f12 and find it in the Resources tab, loaded and ready to play. Is there a way around this? I know Developer Tools is impossible to remove, but is there a way to (say) remove our data from that tab after the plays are up, or similar?

Thanks.

Comment: Any time you send data to my computer, I can get save it. If you give it to me once, It's mine. Worst case: I record the audio output. What are you gonna do then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All major browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari and even IE) has some kind of developer tools. As far as I know, you can't disable it.

But this is a battle you can't win. Even if you where successfully able to prevent them from playing the file multiple times on the computer, you can't prevent them from recoding the audio externally (either by connecting a recoding device to the computer or using a recoding device to record what comes out from the speakers/headphones).

I don't think it's worth too much time to try to obfuscate it. It only makes it harder for the developers and maintainers.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't just an issue with Chrome, Firebug will get that information as well.  Any time a user gets a resource online it will have a reference link.

Comment: Can I somehow unload the resource when the user's plays are up?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest.  I'd definitely look into requiring something in the session to be able to access those resources. At least that limits the possibility of people getting the files while not logged in to the service.

Answer (score 0):

Usually closed environments have a custom computer setup, which disables most features of the computer. in particular it also has a minimalistic browser.

If you're going to allow people to have access with a fully-fledged browser, you also have to take into account: is it worth the time it takes to go through the Developer Tools just to access the resources?

Comment: The point of the project is to remove the need for a closed environment as much as possible. If I, a technologically-apt student wants to hear a conversation three times instead of two, Developer Tools would be the first place I'd look.

Comment: But are the people taking the test as "technologically apt" as you?